# Is $f(x) = 2x+1$ injective? Is it surjective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

How would I answer this? I know what it means to be surjective and injective.
Is the function $f(x)=2x+1$ injective? Is it surjective? Give reasons for your answers.
I assume they are both because there is one output for every input.

Comment: From where to where?

Comment: It depends: If the range of definition is a field of char. 2, it's the constant map $\equiv 1$ :)

Comment: Hey. First, remember to tell us where the function goes from and where it goes to, like André Nicolas asked. Is it $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$? Second, you often get a better response, if you include your own thoughts.

Comment: Please indicate what you've already done/tried and what you think about the problem. This lets others give an answer better suited to your background. It also shows that you aren't just trying to get someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: That's all I was given, that's why I have no idea what to do.

Comment: @Ninjascroll86 so are you saying that you have copied the problem exactly as it was written, word for word?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah

Comment: Ok, then I suggest doing two cases. What if the function maps from the real numbers to the real numbers, so $f\colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$. Is it surjective and/or injective? What if it is a map from the integers to itself, i.e. $f\colon\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$?

Comment: Is it a part of a larger problem set?  For example somewhere would it say "For problems 10-18, determine if the functions from $\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}$ are injective,surjective,both, or neither."  That, or it should be clear from context what the domain and codomain are supposed to be.  If you really aren't told, then when writing your answers, state what assumptions you make (*It is probably safe to assume that the functions are meant to be from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ for introductory examples*), but you might mention why if it was something else (E.g. $\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}$) what happens.

Comment: @Ninjascroll86 that's unusual, but fine.  I suppose that they probably mean that the domain and codomain are both $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Ninjascroll86 your guess is correct, but for the wrong reasons: by definition, any function has one output for every input.  For a function to be injective and surjective, it needs to have *exactly one **input*** for every **output**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "It depends."

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then the function is both surjective and injective. For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$f\left(\frac{1}{2}(x-1)\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{2}(x-1)\right)+1=(x-1)+1=x.$$ Thus $f$ is surjective.

Now suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x_1)&=f(x_2)\\
2x_1+1&=2x_2+1\\
2x_1&=2x_2\\
x_1&=x_2.
\end{align*}
$$

Thus if the images are equal, then the preimages are equal. So $f$ is injective.

Now if $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, then $f$ sends all integers to odd integers. So it cannot be surjective (no even number has a preimage.)

Comment: I'm kinda confused on how you chose $1/2(x−1)$

Comment: Because that is what works. Surjectivity can be tricky to prove sometimes precisely because you have to figure what goes into the function to get a predetermined answer.

Comment: Ahh ok, I kinda get it, you basically want to make it where you get x in the end.

Comment: Sometimes you have to play around with it a bit, but in this case it's not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the domain and the range are $\mathbb R$. Injective means that for all distinct $x_1,x_2$, $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. You can try proving its contraposition: if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x_1=x_2$.

To prove that the function is surjective, you can try for every $y\in \mathbb R$, there exists an $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=y$